# Does emacs have an equivalent to jetbrains' "find action by name" and Atom's Command Palette?

Tags: emacs, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor, jetbrains-ide

These "find any command" dialog in these IDEs/editors makes new features and keyboard shortcuts much more discoverable.

Does Emacs have an equivalent? M-x sort of works, but it's missing a hint of the keybinding annotation and also isn't quite as fluid with the autocomplete compared as these cases.

Comment: Good question. Related ways to discover commands, besides generally good menus, are `discover` and `hydras`: https://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/12/21/discoverel-discover-emacs-context-menus/ and https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - `apropos-command`, bound to <kbd>C-h a</kbd>. From the help page:

> Show commands (interactively callable functions) that match PATTERN.
>   PATTERN can be a word, a list of words (separated by spaces),
>   or a regexp (using some regexp special characters).  If it is a word,
>   search for matches for that word as a substring.  If it is a list of words,
>   search for matches for any two (or more) of those words.

The other help commands are also very useful - <kbd>C-g ?</kbd> to see them all. Similar to `apropos-command` are: `describe-key` <kbd>C-h k</kbd>, which describes the function bound to a key sequence; `describe-variable` <kbd>C-h v</kbd>, which should be obvious; and `describe-bindings` <kbd>C-h b</kbd>, which lists all currently defined keys.

Comment: Even more similar to `apropos-command` are all the other `apropos-*` commands. See (naturally) `M-x apropos-command RET apropos RET`

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> can be nicer with good completion:

[image: counsel-M-x]

You need to install the `counsel` package from MELPA and bind the command:

```cl
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'counsel-M-x)
```

As you can see, the key binding is listed for each bound command. The
query is a regex (hence the initial `^`), spaces are wild (i.e. `.*`).
Additionally, if you install `smex` package from MELPA, your favorite
commands will be listed ahead of other matching commands; this is
remembered across Emacs sessions (in `~/.smex_items` file).

Here are some similar commands:

```cl
(global-set-key (kbd "<f1> f") 'counsel-describe-function)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f1> v") 'counsel-describe-variable)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f1> l") 'counsel-load-library)
```

Note also that you need this setting for the extra minibuffer faces:

```cl
(setq ivy-display-style 'fancy)
```

Comment: IIUC you can also install the `swiper` package from GNU ELPA, which comes with `counsel.el`.

Comment: You're right. The ELPA version is 1 month behind though. I'll update it now.